# Http/Https Mixed Content error when app published in Release mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First off, I want to state: *Yes, I know releasing in debug mode is bad practice, but it's what my team has been doing since day one, and I've only been on this project for the last month... I'm trying to change their ways.*

When I release the .NET MVC 4.5 app in debug mode, everything works as expected. When I release in release mode, while my app seems to build and publish successfully, I am getting strange errors. My CSS files are misnamed (seemingly random series of characters) and some of them aren't getting loaded because of a Mixed Content error. They're all referenced via relative paths, so there is no explicit call to an http address.

Everything I've read has associated this with a faulty server configuration. The app has the following in Web.config, so shouldn't it be redirecting local connections to HTTPS?

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Perhaps there's a setting that I need to change when switching from debug to release mode? Or my configuration is incorrect?

Comment: My team is having this exact same problem when publishing with release mode. Fingers crossed someone has a fix.